# How to use Eclipse for C# scripting instead of Visual Studio?

Tags: unity, eclipse

https://discussions.unity.com/t/how-to-use-eclipse-for-c-scripting-instead-of-visual-studio/330038

"I use *Eclipse* IDE for *Java* development. I am trying to get it to work with *C#*, a programming language I am new to, and *Unity*, which I am also new to. So far, I have installed the [*Eclipse aCute*](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.acute) plugin from the marketplace. However, the *Unity* namespace is not recognized, and autocomplete is not working."
[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

I got one response on the *Unity* discussions forum advising I install an extension. I am looking on the *Eclipse* marketplace, but can not seem to find any results for *Unity*. Is *Unity* development simply unsupported for *Eclipse*, or is there a way to import the Unity namespace?

Comment: Unity doesn't support eclipse, so you cant really without plug-ins. I don't fully know what your talking about, you can use any text editor in Unity as long as the code is correct. By the looks of it, your trying to run the script inside of Eclipse. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: My best guess is just that Unity uses solutions, (.sln) as sort of project files, which are native to .NET. Hence the reason Unity uses Visual Studio.

Comment: Eclipse only supports Java and related languages out-of-the-box. Unity uses C#, another programming language entirely. There probably are C# plugins for Eclipse but I would highly recommend using an IDE that is meant for C# development, such as Visual Studio or my personal favourite JetBrains Rider. For a beginner I would not try to mess with C# plugins for Eclipse and simply use one of these IDE:s. If you do not want to re-learn hotkeys you can import your Eclipse hotkeys into your IDE of choice (google "import Eclipse hotkeys into MY_IDE", replace "MY_IDE" with your IDE of choice).

Comment: You're much better off learning a supported IDE than trying to cobble together a C# workflow in Eclipse. For one thing, you won't be able to debug in an unsupported IDE.